# Phonon.VideoWidget doesn't display with WA_TranslucentBackground property set

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, phonon

I'm building a small video player into my PySide application, a process which I've done on numerous projects before. However, the parent window for the videoWidget has the WA_TranslucentBackground property set, which in turn causes the videoWidget to disappear.

Current code, which prevents the videoWidget from being shown (audio still plays):

```
class Parent(object):
def setupUi(self, Parent):
    Parent.setObjectName("Main")
    Parent.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    Parent.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

Code which will correctly show the videoWidget:

```
class Parent(object):
def setupUi(self, Parent):
    Parent.setObjectName("Main")
    Parent.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    #Parent.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
```

The obvious solution would be to not have a translucent parent window, but I'd really prefer to maintain the translucent window if possible. Is there a simple/known fix to this issue?

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785150/how-to-play-a-video-on-a-translucent-qwidget) post explores this issue under C++; it appears to be due to the QPainter's composition mode. Does anyone have any idea how to change Phonon's videoWidget QPainter composition mode?

Comment: Have you asked at qtcentre? I usually go there after a few days here w/o an answer.

Comment: I haven't, but thank you for the suggestion. It appears to be a known issue, so I've modified the design for the time being to avoid it.